# Does Android (Cupcake) already use Skyhook Wireless for localization?

Tags: android, localization, wireless

I have just been integrating the Skyhook Wireless technology into my Android application. This is the localization framework that gives a better localization by looking for wifi hotspots. As a result the position is better, at least indoors when it can find a hotspot. On the downside the library is around 300kb of size on the device.

Now in Cupcake when I look at "Security & location" settings, there is an option named "Use wireless networks". This seems to be exactly the same as Skyhooks technology. However, I cant find any useful information about what kind of localization this is and weather it makes sense to drop the 300 kb library. Is Skyhook already integrated into Cupcake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't Skyhook but it does the same sort of thing.

Android uses a Google technology similar to what Skyhook offer to calculate your current location using Cell ID and WiFi hotspots. They've been using the same technology to power the 'My Location' option in Google Maps for Mobile for a while ([more details on their blog](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2008/06/google-enables-location-aware.html)).

One of the advantages of using the native Android Location-Based Services is that you can write your app so that it uses either GPS or 'Wireless' depending on your choice, user preferences, available hardware, or a set of [criteria you specify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProviders(android.location.Criteria,%20boolean)) (including power-cost or accuracy).

Comment: They refer to the Assisted-GPS 9or AGPS).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Phone